# Web-scraping Adidas not returning html text

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to web-scrape shoes from Adidas using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
print(webpage)
```

For some reason, it does not seem to retrieve the page's html, though the code seems to work for other urls such as "http://www.python.org". Could this be a security issue? If so, how can I scrape the shoes from the site?

I don’t seem to get an error or response. The code just seems to run indefinitely.

Comment: I think you are right that it is most likely a security issue as I did a simple CURL request for that URL and I got a 403 Forbidden message with some text around security.

Comment: @SartajSinghGill Thanks for trying. Please consider upvoting post for visibility

Comment: Might be useful to also post what error you receive or anything that you see in your log when you run this ? Will help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @SartajSinghGill Added, thanks

Comment: It looks like the Adidas site is using more ways than just the `User-Agent` header field to detect what browser is connecting. Using CURL or wget also gets a 'Connection was reset' after a long wait, the Python component just waits forever it seems. You probably need to use a proper browser, for example using a tool like selenium from Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code worked for me  when I used User-Agent same as in request header :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
html_page = requests.get("https://www.adidas.com/us/men-shoes", headers=hdr, timeout=15)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
soup
```

[image: Sample File input and output Screenshots][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QQan.png)